# Cargar un mismo RecyclerView con datos de dos tablas o mas de SQLite

Tags: java, android

Lo que deseo es hacer que en un `Cardview` aparezcan los datos de la `tabla1` y en la siguiente `CardView` los datos de la `tabla2`. He intentado introducir los datos en el metodo `onBindViewHolder` pero no lo he logrado. Esto es lo que he intentado hacer:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder._info.setText(tabla1.get(position).getInfo_estadistica());
        holder._seleccion.setText(tabla1.get(position).getSeleccion());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(tabla1.get(position).getTitulo_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(tabla1.get(position).getImagen_CV());
        holder._logo.setImageResource(tabla1.get(position).getLogo_equipo());
        holder._info.setText(tabla2.get(position).getInfoEq1_estadistica());
        holder._seleccion.setText(tabla2.get(position).getSeleccion_Eq1());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(tabla2.get(position).getTitulo_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(tabla2.get(position).getImagen_CV());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //Obtener la cantidad de CardView que el Recycler va a cargar
    return size = (tabla1.size() + tabla2.size());
}
```

Sólo pongo estos dos métodos considerando que aquí es donde se introducen los datos a los `views`.

Answer (score 1):

Así como tienes tu código lo que hace es escribir todos esos datos en cada item, opino que lo que necesitas es un if donde le indiques si es tabla 1 o tabla n, así el recyclerview pintara los datos de la tabla 1 en un item y los datos de la tabla n en el item n y así según el numero de items de tu lista.

ejemplo:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(tipoTabla == tabla1){
        holder._info.setText(tabla1.get(position).getInfo_estadistica());
        holder._seleccion.setText(tabla1.get(position).getSeleccion());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(tabla1.get(position).getTitulo_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(tabla1.get(position).getImagen_CV());
        holder._logo.setImageResource(tabla1.get(position).getLogo_equipo());
    }else if(tipoTabla == tablaN){
        holder._info.setText(tabla2.get(position).getInfoEq1_estadistica());
        holder._seleccion.setText(tabla2.get(position).getSeleccion_Eq1());
        holder.tituloCV.setText(tabla2.get(position).getTitulo_CV());
        holder.fondoCV.setImageResource(tabla2.get(position).getImagen_CV());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mas o menos algo así es lo que estoy haciendo, al final decidí guardar cada tabla en un Cardview diferente usando lógicamente el mismo Recycler. Y el problema de los datos lo estoy solucionando almacenando las dos tablas en una sola lista de datos así puedo manejarla a mi gusto dentro del adaptador del Recycler.

Gracias de todos modos por responder!!!